# SCrypt produces different result on x64 platform

Tags: scrypt

I am using this library https://github.com/wg/scrypt in my android app.
I can successfully compile it and bind the native implementation in my android app, but the scryptN function produces a different result if it is execute in a 32bit or 64bit environment, how can it be possible?
The java implementation instead works well on both environments

To reproduce the problem, just build the shared libraries with NDK and try to run this function

```
public String hashPassword(String plainPassword) {
        final int shift = 14;
        final int n = 1 << shift;
        final int r = 8;
        final int p = 1;
        final int dklen = 64;

        try {
            return ByteUtils.toHexString(SCrypt.scrypt(
                plainPassword.getBytes("utf-8"),
                "theseed".getBytes("utf-8"),
                n, r, p, dklen));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogHelper.e("error hashing password", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

you will get different outputs if you run on a 32bit architecture or a 64bit one

Thank you

Comment: Examples code and sample input/output?

Comment: While it may be very "leet" to put all the calls in one jumble it is virtually impossible to debug. Breakout the calls `plainPassword.getBytes` and `theseed".getBytes` into intermediate variables and they examine them in hex. The first step in debugging is to verify the inputs. Make code for the next reader and debugger, let the compiler handle optimizations, the intermediate variable are generally combined during compiler optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

for anyone using this library on Android, I suggest to use this fork instead

https://github.com/lhunath/scrypt

It has a full android ndk project setup, you just have to run ndk-build from the src/android/jni folder (of course you need to have NDK properly configured) and it will generate a working set of .so files.

NOTE: you have to change the Application.mk file in order to generate them for all platforms